# MD5 hash in android or java

Tags: java, android, encryption, md5

I required to convert string in MD5 hash.

I am using

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String bytesToHex( byte[] bytes )
    {
        char[] hexChars = new char[ bytes.length * 2 ];
        for( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ )
        {
            int v = bytes[ j ] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[ j * 2 ] = hexArray[ v >>> 4 ];
            hexChars[ j * 2 + 1 ] = hexArray[ v & 0x0F ];
        }
        return new String( hexChars );
    }
```

It is giving output like this website http://www.md5.cz/

but I required to generate hash as this http://webcodertools.com/hashstring giving output.

Please use **test** in both sites.

with using above function I am getting o/p like first site but I need as second site is  giving.

Is there any different function or am I missing something in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second web site is simply using base64 instead of hex to represent the binary data as text. So you can get rid of your `bytesToHex` method entirely, and just use [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html):

```
String base64Digest = Base64.encodeToString(thedigest, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

(As an aside, I'd avoid using `the` as a prefix in variable names - it provides no benefit, and is just cruft.)

Comment: i have changed code as per your suggestion.. and its working fine... really big thanks :)

Comment: I think `Base64.NO_WRAP` should be used instead of `Base64.DEFAULT`. `Base64.DEFAULT` will generate newline at the end of the base64 string.

Answer (score -1):

Use this method it will return in the same format

```
public static String getMd5Hash(String input) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
        String md5 = number.toString(16);
        while (md5.length() < 32)
           md5 = "0" + md5;
        return md5;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
         Log.e("MD5", e.getLocalizedMessage());
      return null;
    }
    }
```

---

This returns in //**4a2028eceac5e1f4d252ea13c71ecec6** format MD5 of "WHAT" and

```
String base64format =  Base64.encodeToString(thedigest, Base64.DEFAULT); //as given by @Jon Skeet
```

will return in the format as **SiAo7OrF4fTSUuoTxx7Oxg==**

---

Sorry for vice-versa solution.

Comment: No, that will return hex, which is what the OP's code is already doing in a rather nicer way IMO. The OP *wants* it in base64, as per the second link. Additionally, your answer assumes the OP has data as a string when the sample code shows bytes, and uses the platform default encoding to convert that text to bytes. Finally, your code would be much easier to read if you indented it nicely.